# ArrayList parameter type in ServerRpc

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I created custom component , simply I used IDE generated component.

> RightClick on project > New > Vaadin Widget

and add **xxxWidgetset.gwt.xml** and inherits from main project widgetset.gwt.xml. My component structure as below.

[image: my component structure]

And changed parameter types of some ServerRpc methods with **java.util.ArrayList** , and invoke from some events.

I got the below error logs at my console.

```
Aug 09, 2014 5:01:17 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.decodeCustomType(JsonCodec.java:316)
at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.decodeInternalOrCustomType(JsonCodec.java:275)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.parseServerRpcInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:462)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.parseInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:395)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.parseInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:338)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:206)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:168)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1405)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why ? I think Vaadin component's RPC methods aren't support for **java.util.ArrayList**. Am I right ?

Comment: I used vaadin version 7.2.4 and Tomcat 7

Comment: **java.util.HashMap** work fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `List` instead of `ArrayList`. According to this bug ticket http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/11669 `ArrayList` is broken with server to client RPC but `List` should work.